# Why do I need sklearn in docker container if I already have the model as a pickle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, scikit-learn, pickle

I pickled a model and want to expose only the `prediction` api written in `Flask`. However when I write a dockerfile to make a image without `sklearn` in it, I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.xxxx'` where `xxx` refers to sklearn's ML algorithm classes, at the point where I am loading the model using pickle like `classifier = pickle.load(f)`.

When I rewrite the dockerfile to make an image that has `sklearn` too, then I don't get the error even though in the API I **never** import `sklearn`.
My concept of pickling is very simple, that it will serialize the classifier class with all of its data. So when we unpickle it, since the classifier class already has a `predict` attribute, we can just call it. Why do I need to have `sklearn` in the environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a misconception of how pickle works.

It does *not* seralize anything, except of instance state (`__dict__` by default, or custom implementation). When unpickling, it just tries to create instance of corresponding class (here goes your import error) and set pickled state.

There's a reason for this: you don't know beforehand what methods will be used after `load`, so you can not pickle implementation. In addition to this, in pickle time you can not build some AST to see what methods/modules will be needed after deserializing, and main reason for this is dynamic nature of python — your implementation can actually vary depending on input.

After all, even assuming that theoretically we'd have smart self-contained pickle serialization, it will be actual model + sklearn in single file, with no proper way to manage it.

Comment: Could you please expand AST?

Comment: I have almost understood it. However what still doesn't make sense to me is the fact that, if sklearn is not actually imported, then how is it used by the prediction API in the background? This is uncharted territory for me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree. I mean, for statically typed/compiled languages you can make "partial" compilation and get what you'd like to see, for python you'd need to make deep analysis of what and how you call from your methods. Installing sklearn + pickle.load + model.predict(...) is ok on api side, nothing wrong with that — you need model to predict, model state is pickled, model class is part of sklearn

Comment: + you can export sklearn models as PMML and load it to any machinery that does support it. But anyway, you'll need _something_ that makes calculations based on your weights/connections. It may be sklearn pipeline/model, tensorflow thing, some c/java code based on PMML, but anyway — there will be model + state. If you're in python + sklearn "realm", sklearn is your dependency, install it in your container, same way as flask.

Comment: Things are unraveling now. I wanted to confirm, is it safe to say that, even though we do not explicitly import sklearn, we still need it if we are unpickling its objects, **as a runtime dependency** of some sort?

Comment: Yes. 99% of  python is runtime, literally.

Answer (score 1):

The pickle is just the representation of the data inside the model. You still need the code to use it, that's why you need to have `sklearn` inside the container.